# Creating WordPress with multiple themes

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to make a static website however depending on the page I will be able to edit some of the content in WordPress.

I created the homage and it looks great, then I duplicated the page, renamed it to `about.php`, and changed some of the code.

When I visit the url the about page doesn't come up just my `index.php` again. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress might use a different template to render the URL you requested.

I suggest reviewing how WordPress looks for templates: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy:

> "Which template file(s) will WordPress use when it displays a certain type of page?"

There's also a [visual overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

Then you should be able to name the file according to your targets.

Comment: what if i want more then one type of page. the visual overview looks like there is just one page

Comment: It looks for more specialized versions as well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display: in order [1] the page template you manually select for a page http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates, [2] page-{slug}.php - If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look to use page-recent-news.php, [3] page-{id}.php - If the page ID is 6, WordPress will look to use page-6.php, [4] page.php, [5] index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I use Theme Mantra with which you can choose the display of each page to different settings and add sidebars as you want.